# Detecting a function taking more than expected in R

Tags: r

I implemented a function that sometimes falls in infinite loop. In brief, it crawls data from web with [rvest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf), and simply being halted while it fetches data. It is pretty rare like once-twice a month, but is critical, so therefore, I wish to detect it with time limit, i.e. it takes more than expected. I wonder if there is a standard way to do that.

I know there is a R library that does, which I read article around one year ago if I remember correctly, but I failed to google it.

Comment: Is function defined by you?

Comment: The title is misleading. Yo uwant to detect if it takes longer than a fixed amount whicch is infinitely easier than deteciting infintite loop.

Comment: An easy way would be to set a maximum value for your iterator and break when it reaches it.

Comment: `withTimeout` should help you.

Comment: @MKR Yes that function is what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @MKR Post as answer? Or close as duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function (`withTimeout`) which can help. The function is defined in "R.utils" package as:

```
withTimeout(expr, envir=parent.frame(), timeout, cpu=timeout, elapsed=timeout,
  onTimeout=c("error", "warning", "silent"), ...)
```

The example code provided in `R documentation`:

```
res <- withTimeout({
  foo();                           # Function to be called foo
}, timeout=1.08, onTimeout="silent");
```